# Speedup Testing with Force.com IDE using slim Logs - but how to set the log-level?

Tags: unit-test, ide, eclipse, performance

A lot has been written here about slow development in general and slow testing in particular e. g.:

- [Slow development](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11084/slow-development)
- [Faster unit tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/faster-unit-tests/3697#3697)

For my use case I found one reason for slow testing while playing with the Developer Console: Default log-levels are in most tools something like FINE. This may cause very huge log-files and in my case very slow response times (about 2 minutes). Setting the log-levels to ERROR or WARN reduced the waiting-time from 2 minutes to 3 seconds. WOW! That's what I wanted ;-)

Trying to apply what I have just learned to my preferred tools I opened eclipse. But as an unfortunate there in the Force.com IDE it always creates verbose FINE-like logs, even after picking the lowest level for all Log-Categories in the slider... I tried it with v31 on eclipse-4.4 and also v29 on eclipse-4.3. Both nearly the same and it still wastes ~2 minutes for logs I don't need. Something I'm doing wrong here.

Has anyone an idea on how to get rid of this bloated logs in eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found it!

**Version 31**

Don't set it to NONE, set it to ERROR or WARN and the bulky logs will go away. Performance is fast as Developer Console. I think NONE doesn't stands for NO LOGS, but maybe for NOT SET USE DEFAULT.

[image]

**Version 29**

In the older version there are less slider-options... But I was able to get nearly the same speed using

- Apex code ==> ERROR or WARN
- all the other settings ==> NONE