# Is there a way to view recently changed Apex Classes in Salesforce?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I can see multiple use cases for this, but today's case is: When deploying, we have to choose classes to add to the change set. It would make it much easier to know what classes to add if we could sort the classes by what has recently changed.

Second use case: Something that was recently working on Sandbox now isn't working; what changed?

On the main Apex Classes page, there is a *Last Modified By* column, but it has the user name and the date that it was changed. If you sort by that column, the sort is done by the username. I tried creating a new view, but there is no column for last modified date.

In the *Choose components to add to your change set* page, it only lists the class name, with no other information. Not very helpful.

I'm guessing there is a way to do this in Eclipse, but I'm not very familiar with it, and don't see it yet. Even if there is a way in Eclipse, it would still be nice to easily and quickly view changes.
Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could export Setup Audit Trail and sort/filter it in Excel for example. Not terribly convenient but it's something.

Listviews - no luck I think. And seeing that SF is keen to make Setup less and less useful (recently hidden code coverage column for example) I wouldn't count on much.

With changesets it sometimes helps to check dependencies list and quickly select stuff there.

---

Note that the proper answer should be "go seriously give Eclipse a go", especially coupled with some [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (Subversion? Git?) and eventually - tool for automated deployment of changes (Jenkins?).

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Force.com_with_Subversion_for_Team_Development

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBKAA0

http://www.salesforce.com/heroku/ - uses Git to push changes, maybe Force.com platform will use it eventually too

See [Development Team Best Practices, or "Is this IDE for real? I am in disbelief"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/development-team-best-practices-or-is-this-ide-for-real-i-am-in-disbelief) too ;)

Comment: Thanks @eyescream. I really wish Eclipse were a better tool. I find it very frustrating when compared to Visual Studio, JetBrains products, etc. I think that last link sums it up really well. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/development-team-best-practices-or-is-this-ide-for-real-i-am-in-disbelief

Comment: @AdrianCarr You may want to also look at the other answer; a quick query can give you at least a quick overview of what's changed when. Directly from Eclipse or the Developer Console, no less.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Actually, I posted the other answer in case it would help anyone else. ;~) Cheers, Adrian

Answer (score 19):

A coworker gave me this. It's a fast, easy SOQL Query that does just what I want:

```
SELECT Name, LastModifiedDate FROM ApexClass order by Lastmodifieddate desc
```

VisualForce Pages can be found with this:

```
SELECT Name, LastModifiedDate FROM ApexPage order by Lastmodifieddate desc
```

Triggers:

```
SELECT Name, LastModifiedDate FROM ApexTrigger order by Lastmodifieddate desc
```

Comment: You can check Aura (lightning) bundles with this:
   SELECT  DeveloperName, LastModifiedDate FROM AuraDefinitionBundle order by Lastmodifieddate desc

Answer (score 4):

This problem so frustrated me that I wrote a chrome extension to help.

It adds last modified date to the change set list, and orders the items to add by most recently modified first.  It has search/filter/order etc. You can also compare to other sandboxes or prod -- this will show the last modified date/user of the compared org and you can view the differences by selecting it.

Find it here:  [Salesforce Change Set Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-hel/gdjfanbphogooppaefebaaoohdcigpoi/reviews)